# Write snowflake stored procedure in SQL and JS using for loop

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table contains the order data and has columns `city`, `date`, `orders`, `total_sales`.

Write a Snowflake procedure in SQL and JS containing 'For Loop ' to get the most grossing day( in terms of total_sales) of the month for each city within the given dataset.

For the following dates, also Orders for each country.

Write procedure in both SQL and Javascript.

Can someone please help.

Input:

| City | Date | Revenue | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 01 February 2023 | $50 | 5 |
| a | 01 February 2023 | $49 | 2 |
| b | 01 February 2023 | $36 | 5 |
| a | 02 February 2023 | $45 | 8 |
| b | 02 February 2023 | $56 | 6 |
| c | 02 February 2023 | $56 | 7 |
| d | 03 February 2023 | $66 | 5 |
| a | 04 March 2023 | $88 | 5 |
| a | 05 March 2023 | $58 | 5 |
| b | 04 March 2023 | $54 | 8 |

Output:

| City | Maxium Grossing date of each month | Revenue | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 01 February 2023 | $100 | 10 |
| a | 03 March 2023 | $120 | 15 |
| a | 04 April 2023 | $180 | 25 |
| b | 05 February 2023 | $250 | 12 |
| b | 28 March 2023 | $285 | 58 |
| b | 21 April 2023 | $52 | 25 |

I used for loop but i allows me to iterate through rows and not through column's to get maximum revenue.

Comment: Hello, welcome, your question is interesting but it is not the correct way to ask on stackoverflow. You must provide code, whatever you have tried, edit your question and someone may help you.

Comment: Code, table definitions, sample data, required result. All as editable text, no images

Comment: Hi @Akshay_P3 could you please provide the sample output?

Comment: your example input and output do not match.

Answer (score 0):

So this rather clearly is school assignment. Because "use stored procedure, and do it twice in two languages" is clear a "go learn how to use stored procedures." instruction.

To be honest, this is useful to tech you how to do these, but this is not how this should be done, stored procedures should almost never be used to process all rows, so to some degree what-ever education you are getting is of low value (in the context of how should the tool be used). It would almost be more value to use a User Defined Table Function, and get snowflake to do the aggregation.

But really how this problem should be solved is in pure SQL. So instead of doing your learning for you. I will show you how you should actually solve "this problem", and encourage you to actually do the study of LOOPS in stored procedures, of which when you get stuck on those steps you should ask questions about that..

### real SQL solution:

data creation:

```
create or replace table data as 
    select 
        $1 as city, 
        to_date($2, 'dd mon yyyy') as date,
        $3 as revenue,
        $4 as orders
    from values
    ('a', '01 February 2023','50', 5),
    ('a', '01 February 2023','49', 2),
    ('b', '01 February 2023','36', 5),
    ('a', '02 February 2023','45', 8),
    ('b', '02 February 2023','56', 6),
    ('c', '02 February 2023','56', 7),
    ('d', '03 February 2023','66', 5),   
    ('a', '04 March 2023','88', 5),
    ('a', '05 March 2023','58', 5),
    ('b', '04 March 2023','54', 8)
;
```

So one part of the SQL to get the sum's of the monthly revenue and orders, putting your

```
select
    city,
    sum(revenue) as revenue,
    sum(orders) as orders
from data
group by city, date_trunc('month', date)
order by city, date_trunc('month', date);
```

[image]

righto, but how to get the "highest date" inside that same grouping, [MAX_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by), we will tell it to return the date that has the max revenue

```
select
    city,
    max_by(date, revenue) as long_name,
    sum(revenue) as revenue,
    sum(orders) as orders
from data
group by city, date_trunc('month', date)
order by city, date_trunc('month', date);
```

[image]

Zero need to LOOP, which should be avoid at all performance cost.

And if you want some formatting because long form dates have special meaning to you:

```
select
    city,
    to_char(max_by(date, revenue), 'dd mon yyyy') as "Maxium Grossing date of each month",
    sum(revenue) as revenue,
    sum(orders) as orders
from data
group by city, date_trunc('month', date)
order by city, date_trunc('month', date);
```

[image]

The real purpose of stored procedures, is to do second order processing, aka, I have a table that names other tables for each row in the first table do some expensive work of the secondary tables. Thus the per-row-overhead, of the stored procedure is low.